# Swap the column Values if value in a column is negative

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table which has 2 columns i.e. debit_amount and credit_amount.  I need to extract the data from this table and swap the values if they are negative.

Actual Table

```
TABLE A

Account no   CREDIT    DEBIT
   1           500      0
   2          -322       0
   3          -869       0
   4           0         500
   5           0        -100
```

Required Output

```
  Account no   CREDIT    DEBIT
       1           500      0
       2           0       322 
       3           0       869
       4           0        500
       5          100        0
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have to `update` the table?

Comment: No, only extract the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `case` expression.

```
select accountno
,case when credit=0 and debit < 0 then -1*debit 
      when credit < 0 then 0 
 else credit end as credit
,case when debit=0 and credit < 0 then -1*credit 
      when debit < 0 then 0 
 else debit end as debit
from tblA
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for...Thanks!

Comment: Why `-1*debit` instead of a simple `-debit`?

Comment: @dnoeth .. you are right..it didn't cross my mind when posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient way to perform this task, but you could also iterate over each line and check the values using a cursor. This might give you more flexibility if you have additional logic in the future.

```
declare @TABLE_A table ([Account No] int, CREDIT int, DEBIT int)
declare @TABLE_B table ([Account No] int, CREDIT int, DEBIT int)

insert into @TABLE_A
values 
(1, 500, 0),
(2, -322, 0),
(3, -869, 0),
(4, 0, 500),
(5, 0, -100)

set nocount on
set quoted_identifier off

declare @acct_no int, @cred int, @deb int 

declare iteration cursor GLOBAL STATIC for
        -- Begin statement for cursor array
        select [Account No], CREDIT, DEBIT from @TABLE_A
        -- End statement for cursor array

open iteration
  fetch first from iteration into @acct_no, @cred, @deb -- get first row

 while @@fetch_status=0 
 begin
 if @cred < 0
 begin
 set @deb = @cred * -1
 set @cred = 0
 end

 if @deb < 0 
 begin
 set @cred = @deb * -1
 set @deb = 0
 end

 insert into @TABLE_B
 values (@acct_no, @cred, @deb)

fetch next from iteration into @acct_no, @cred, @deb  --next row

end -- while @@FETCH_STATUS=0

close iteration

deallocate iteration

set nocount off

select * from @TABLE_B
```